# ASP.NET List View ImageButton Command Argument

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I pass `'<%# Eval("Url") %>'` as a `CommandArgument` to my

```
protected void ImageButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var link = (string) e.CommandArgument;
}
```

method? Whenever I do it like below I receive empty `e.CommandArgument`.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <td runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFBD6; color: #333333;">
        <asp:ImageButton 
        ID="Column1Label" 
        runat="server"
        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Url") %>'
        OnCommand="ImageButton_Command" 
        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Column1") %>'
        Width="300" 
        Height="300" 
        CssClass="ListItem"
        EnableViewState="False" 
        CommandName="Sort"></asp:ImageButton>
        <br/> 
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this:   `EnableViewState="False"`

Turn View State back on (delete that line) and it should work.